# python mechanize retrieving files larger than 1GB

Tags: python-2.7, mechanize-python

I am trying to download some files via mechanize. Files smaller than 1GB are downloaded without causing any trouble. However, if a file is bigger than 1GB the script runs out of memory:

The mechanize_response.py script throws out of memory at the following line
self.__cache.write(self.wrapped.read())

__cache is a cStringIO.StringIO, It seems that it can not handle more than 1GB.

How to download files larger than 1GB?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think the StringIO can't handle it? Isn't it more likely that your program has run out of memory?  Try running it on a 64 bit machine with more memory.

Comment: My machine is 64 bit machine. And the I have 8GB ram and that's the only program running.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to download the file into memory but you don't have enough.  Try using the `retrieve` method with a file name to stream the downloaded file to disc.

Comment: That's what I am already using. I also tried using browser.open() and I am reading the file in chunks then writing it to a localfile but I still get the same error out of memory after 1GB but this time from read() in in mechanize _responce.py

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out a work around. 
Other than using browser.retrieve or browser.open I used **mechanize.urlopen** which returned the urllib2 Handler. This allowed me to download files larger than 1GB.

I am still interested in figuring out how to make retrieve work for files larger than 1GB.

Comment: Sounds like this is the best answer so far.  Can I suggest you expand the question to show the retrieve statement you are using - that will make the question and answer more useful to other readers - which is the point of stack overflow.